# Please help to understand text about closed operators and extensions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I need help understanding a section of a book I'm reading (Mathematical Foundations Of Quantum Mechanics, by J. von Neumann, Princeton U. Press, 1955, pages 152-153). I have a few questions on two pages of the text ([see scans here](https://imgur.com/a/FoCFs), also attached below), and if anyone could take the time to address them, I would greatly appreciate it.

1. First, what does it mean when it says (bottom of page 152)

> All $\tilde A'_a$ are extensions of $\tilde A'_0$ [...] All are different from one another, and from $\tilde A'_0$.

(Earlier in the book, $\tilde A$ is defined as the closure of a Hermitian operator: $\tilde Af$ is defined, if a sequence $f1,f2,..$ with defined $Af_n$ exists, in such a way that $f$ is the limit of the $f_n$, and the $Af_n$ also possess the limit $f^*$. Then $\tilde Af=f^*$. Also, an "extension" of an operator $A$ is defined as an operator $B$ such that whenever $Af$ is defined, $Bf$ is also defined and equals $Af$.).

Since the domain of $A'_0$ are all the functions on [0,1] interval with the boundary condition $f(0):f(1) = 0$ and all their linear combinations, the limit points of this domain are all the functions on [0,1] with the boundary condition $f(0):f(1) =e^{-ia}$, and so the domain and values of $\tilde A'_0$  should then coincide with the domain and values of any  $A_n'$ (and also of any $\tilde A_n'$). If so, why does it say that they are all "different from one another and from $\tilde A_0$"?

2 .  Then, on page 153, it says that the unitary operation $f(q) \rightarrow e^{ibq}f(q)$ transforms the space $N_{a}$ into $N_{a+b}$. But, by definition, $N_{a}$ is the space of all functions on [0,1] with the boundary condition $f(0):f(1) =e^{-ia}$, and multiplying each of these functions by $e^{ibq}$ does not change the ratio $f(0):f(1)$, so how could it transform that space into $N_{a+b}$ (where the boundary condition would be $f(0):f(1) =e^{-i(a+b)}$)?!

3 . Finally, on page 153 it says

> "[...] consequently it suffices to show that $\tilde A'_{a}=\tilde A'_{y}$ for $a \neq y$, and this is certainly the case if $A'_{a}$ and $A'_{y}$ possess no common Hermitian extension."

Why does one the latter imply the former? Even though $A'_{a}$ and $A'_{y}$ have no common Hermitian extension, aren't their closures $\tilde A'_{a}$ and $\tilde A'_{y}$ entirely different operators (non Hermitian), with a common domain and values (and therefore should be equal)?

------------------ Scans attached ---------------------

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

Comment: That's very old school. You may want to try Reed and Simon (you can't beat it for an intro to Hilbert space operators). This very same example appears there.

Comment: I would, but I'm already a bit invested (150 pages in) in this book :), and I got just stuck here. Also, would you happen to know the page in Reed and Simon?

Comment: Well...it's in the section where they talk about self adjoint extensions of symmetric operators and examples of such extensions in QM...

Comment: John von Neumann may be old-school now, but he established that school. He established the first theory of closed, unbounded operators by studying their graphs, gave a full description of the selfadjoint extensions of symmetric operators, and proved the first general spectral theorem in the book that JCat is reading. With this he laid the foundations for Quantum, and even proved an ergodic theorem. Most major results for unbounded operators go back to John von Neumann.

Answer (score 1):

1. The self-adjoint extensions of a symmetric operator is not unique, as the example in question shows. One can define the Cayley transform $C_A$ of a symmetric operator $A$. $C_A$ is a partial isometry. Self-adjoint extensions of $A$ correspond to unitary extensions of $C_A$. It's not hard to see there can be many (or no) unitary extensions for a given partial isometry.
2. As your scan says, the boundary condition is that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. The dense domain of the symmetric operator here (the momentum observable) is the set of absolutely continuous functions satisfying that boundary condition. The deficiency indices are $(1,1)$. So the self-adjoint extentions are parameterized by the circle, and translates nicely into the boundary conditions $f(0) = e^{2 \pi i a} f(1)$, for some $a$, in this case.